# Hibernate исключение ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException при использовании метода CriteriaBuilder.orderBy

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

После использования метода `CriteriaBuilder.orderBy` с любыми параметрами я получаю исключение ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException после использования метода `getResultList()`. Запрос работает хорошо, но вот после добавления сортировки для любого поля, то сразу же ломается все.

Код:

```java
CriteriaBuilder criteria = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<LevelWrapper> query = criteria.createQuery(LevelWrapper.class);
Root<LevelWrapper> root = query.from(Level.class);
Join<Level, User> userJoin = root.<Level, User>join("owner", JoinType.INNER);

query.select(levelWrapperConstructor(criteria, root, userJoin));
query.where(applyFilters(criteria, root, filters));
query.orderBy(criteria.desc(root.get("likes"))); // Проблемное место

List<LevelWrapper> levels = entityManager.createQuery(query)
  .setFirstResult(10 * filters.page())
  .setMaxResults(10)
  .getResultList(); // Здесь вылетает исключение
```

Ссылка на стектрейс -> https://paste.dev.su/HgaZrtRT